# Mapping set on new index is ignored

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hi !

I just started to learn ElasticSearch, and my first steps wasn't too bad. I put some data into with the help of the ES library available on Python with the following piece of code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

jsondata(json.dumps("{
    "low": "5.9400",
    "high": "5.9600",
    "id": "555",
    "volume": 1171,
    "timestamp": "2016-08-15 19:01:03"
    }"
)
ES_HOST = {"host" : "localhost", "port" : 9200}
es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [ES_HOST])

    es.create(index="index_test",
              doc_type="tr",
              body=jsondata
          )
```

However, when I wanted to define each type of fields I put, ES just ignore it. I think the way I proceed isn't correct. There is the piece of code I executed just before execute my Python script :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index_test/' -d '"mappings": {
"tr": {
    "_source": {
        "enabled":true
    }
    "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "volume" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "high" : { "type" : "float" },
        "low" : { "type" : "float" },
        "timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
    }
}
}'
```

By default, ES store the data with all fields set as `string`, except the `volume` field, set as `number`. There is the JSON gave by ES via Kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "index_test",
  "_type": "tr",
  "_id": "AVaPJj8Y0iDATupCtaXZ",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "low": "5.9400",
    "high": "5.9600",
    "id": "555",
    "volume": 1171,
    "timestamp": "2016-08-15 19:01:03"
  }
}
```

Anything I forgot ? Maybe I needed to add the settings part ?

Comment: You should insert mapping before inserting data. So delete index, put your mapping, insert data.

Comment: @alpert I just deleted my index via XDELETE, then pushed again my config and executed my script. Then on Kibana I added my Index via the settings page (via "Indices") and fields type are still the same...

Comment: @alpert My error was to put in my code the path of the file instead of the data directly, which I did after. Then when I used Kibana, it erased the configuration as it wasn't well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There it is !

Ok, I've tried to do the following:

```
$curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index_test/
{"acknowledged":true}

$curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index_test/' -d conf/ESConf/ElasticSearchMapping.conf
{"acknowledged":true}

$curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index_test/'
{"index_test":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{},"settings":{"index":  {"conf/ESConf/ElasticSearchMapping":{"conf":""},"creation_date":"1471283566621","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"EZoDAOJNQoiX4VQWs1Sx1w","version":{"created":"2030499"}}},"warmers":{}}}
```

So I forgot to add @ before my path, that's why it did not worked ^^":

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index_test/' -d @conf/ESConf/ElasticSearchMapping.conf
```